# no more then one response from Worker (Typscript)

Tags: typescript, worker

i am having trouble to set up a woker in TS. this is where i call the worker:

```
const sensorMeshWorkerLocation = new URL(
  './sensormesh/filterWorker.ts',
  import.meta.url
)
const sensorMeshWorker = new Worker(sensorMeshWorkerLocation, {
  type: 'module',
})

....
          sensorMeshWorker.postMessage({
            sceneMesh: inputCopy,
            rays: meshPlanes.map((x) => ({
              origin: x.sensorPosition!.asArray(), //, contextMesh),
              direction: x.sensorNormal!.asArray(), //, contextMesh),
            })),
          });
    
          sensorMeshWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
            e.data.map((x: boolean, i: number) => {
              if (meshPlanes.length >= i) {
                meshPlanes[i].ignore = x;
              }
            });
            do something
          };
```

the worker gets called (at least i console-logs that it is running) but i do only get one response from the worker. its so weird because it works one time, and then not another time.

the worker looks like that:

```
    self.addEventListener(
      "message",
      async function (e) {
    
....    
        let collisions = filterMeshWithContext(contextMesh, rays);
    
        self.postMessage(collisions);
     
        // Terminate the worker
        self.close();
      },
      false
    );
```

whats the problem here? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know why i did overlook this, but the Problem is this line:

```
// Terminate the worker
self.close()
```

quite obviouse...